# Cannot find hadoop download locations on apache mirror list

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to download and install hadoop, but every mirror on the list 
http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/

doesn't appear to have hadoop... as i get some variant of

"Not Found
The requested URL /hadoop/common/ was not found on this server."

this seems like a bug.. what is going on? where should i report it?

I have tried several (6-10) of the mirrors all with the same result.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to try this page:
https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/

Comment: This worked for me, but is there a reason why Apache's mirrors don't work?